# How to create a tiled background button using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a button like this (input type="submit"): [image: Simple Button]

using an image that needs to be tiled to achieve the above effect. [image: Image to be tiled]

I have tried doing this so far:

```
            border: none;
            background: url(myImage.png) no-repeat;
            background-size: 80px 40px;
            padding-left: 40px;
            padding-right: 40px;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
```

But looks like it is a lot of playing around with pixels numbers to achieve the desired effect. Is there an easier way of tiling to achieve this effect.

Comment: I added the iOS tag because I am building this specifically for iOS.

Comment: Can you use CSS3? Ok fair enough, but could be misleading if you add ios in and you don't specifically ask anything that has to do with ios.

Comment: You could do something with `gradient` and `border-radius`.

Comment: With your background image, try `text-align:center; line-height:40px`. If that doesn't work, I'd say use a gradient with a stop at 50%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to mess with gradients, here is a simpler way, as I see there isn't actually a gradient in your image, but a two-tone button.

You can achieve this two-tone effect without altering the `HTML` by using the pseudo-element `:before` to add a 50% tall, transparent white div.

If you this method you actually have a reflection on your button, so text and icons inside it will also have that "shine" ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/ySTbB/1/)).

```
#login{
    background:#444;
    display:inline-block;
    color:white;
    padding:10px 60px;
    border-radius:8px;
    position:relative;
}

#login:before{
    content:'';
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ySTbB/

Comment: Well, if he wants `IE<9` support he can use a `1x1` pixel transparent-white image instead of `rgba`. PS: Also I suggest to use `:after` instead of `:before` as the shine is actually on top (after) everything else.

Comment: And IE<8 doesn't support `::before` ;-)

Comment: I stated in the answer, instead of `before` an actual `html` div could be placed inside the button, not a pseudo-element. I would still go for the gradient solution though, as long as he only wants the background of the button to be affected :)

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS3 and border radius

```
-webkit-border-radius: 11px;
-moz-border-radius: 11px;
border-radius: 11px;
background: rgb(76,76,76); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(76,76,76,1)), color-stop(12%,rgba(89,89,89,1)), color-stop(39%,rgba(71,71,71,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(44,44,44,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(60%,rgba(17,17,17,1)), color-stop(91%,rgba(28,28,28,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(19,19,19,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

SRC: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: He said he is building specifically for iOS

Comment: I understand that. But I was trying to figure out a way to do that by using images instead of gradients simply coz I can use it across all browsers or any screen size without having to deal with pixel sizes.

Comment: @ZachL this method does work on IE10 and IE9, IE8 has a fallback with the two-tone and just does a slight gradient for the entire input.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the actual image you want to use as background, it would probably be a better idea to just use CSS:

```
input[type="submit"]
{
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #AAA 49%, #555 50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, if `button-slice.jpg` is a 40px tall, 1px wide jpg "slice" of the background tile pattern.

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 170px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(button-slice.jpg) repeat-x;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

You could also forego images completely and use CSS3 gradients to create that background effect instead, which is probably a better solution if it's only intended for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can use CSS3 I strongly suggest using it as such:

```
input[type="submit"] {
    background: #3e3e3e;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #616161 0%, #777777 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #393939 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#616161), color-stop(50%,#777777), color-stop(51%,#3b3b3b), color-stop(100%,#393939));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #616161 0%,#777777 50%,#3b3b3b 51%,#393939 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #616161 0%,#777777 50%,#3b3b3b 51%,#393939 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #616161 0%,#777777 50%,#3b3b3b 51%,#393939 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #616161 0%,#777777 50%,#3b3b3b 51%,#393939 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#616161', endColorstr='#393939',GradientType=0 );
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: white;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

It'll load a lot faster and render nicer on different DPI devices.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a gradient background with an image as a backup for browsers that do not support gradient. The image bg will tile automatically and the border radius will ensure rounded corners.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/hSwJN/16/

```
#submit {
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius:6px;
display: inline-block;
color: #000;
font-family:'Oswald';
font-size: 20px;
padding: 12px 24px;
border:none;
background:url('http://www.islandpoolnspa.com/More_info_button_background_rot_180.jpg');
background: rgb(76,76,76); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(76,76,76,1)), color-stop(12%,rgba(89,89,89,1)), color-stop(39%,rgba(71,71,71,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(44,44,44,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(60%,rgba(17,17,17,1)), color-stop(91%,rgba(28,28,28,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(19,19,19,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```